# How to Check App was previously installed or not

Tags: android, android-package-managers

How to check if the app was previously installed or not? I know I can search for package manager class for first install time but the value returned from this method can be reset by uninstalling and reinstalling the app. I am talking about apps which are not mine for example if I want to check that Amazon was previously installed or not in mobile then how to do this? I searched StackOverflow but nothing worked for me.

Comment: I'm sure it isn't possible. You shouldn't have access to he information of the apps that user have ever installed.

Comment: @VladMatvienko i sloved it :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no general way to check if an app **was** installed on a device (For security reasons as you can imagine).

But if you aim for a specific app you can try to analyze if there are accessible leftovers of that app on the sdcard for example. And your app can then check based on the existance of that files if the app was installed or not.

If you want to know if one of your **own** apps was installed on the device. you can go with the sdcard approach and write a file to the sdcard and read it with your other app.

Comment: I got the idea, thanks bro. I can check for the last modified folder then if the user install it again from my application I can again check if the value of last modifed is available it means app was previously installed and then values will change again :D . m i right ? :D

Comment: @AmitKhatkar I think yes, it really easy if you want to check if one of your own apps was installed. But if you are not in control of the app you want to check there is a high chance that there are no left overs on the sd card for example.

Comment: if app was installed it will return the first install time else it will return 0 :D

`PackageInfo info = null;
        long firstInstallTime=0;
        try {
            info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(package, 0);
            firstInstallTime = info.firstInstallTime;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.e("firstinstall", String.valueOf(firstInstallTime));`

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using writing file on SD Card:

```
   File f = new File("path of your file & sdcard location");
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        // Already installed your application get the file

    }else{
        // First time installed write a file here
        f.mkdir();
    }
```

Comment: if user will clear there junk file, then this file will be lost. so after that you can not grab this file !..

Comment: your file path should be in sdcard,not in application cache directory or getFilesDir() which can be removed after uninstalled application, it should be in specific location which is stored permanently.

Answer (score -1):

Try this may be it helpful

```
    // Use package name which we want to check
    boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.check.application");  

    if(isAppInstalled) {
        //This intent will help you to launch if the package is already installed
        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.check.application");
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);

        Log.i("Application is already installed.");       
    } else {
        // Do whatever we want to do if application not installed
        // For example, Redirect to play store

        Log.i("Application is not currently installed.");
    }
}

private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: soved it. btw your answer is not correct i don't want to launch an app i just want to check if the app was installed or not.